# Can I perform validation for a specific integer size using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to validate the size of an integer using Hibernate. I have been testing different annotations such as @Size, @Length and @Range but I don't seem to be able validate the specific size of an Integer. They seem to work for Strings, but for Integers its fine for a range but not a specific number. I want to ensure my SortCode field is only 6 digits long.

```
@Column(name = "SortCode", nullable = false)
// @Size(max = 6, min = 6)
// @Length(min = 0, max = 6)
@NotNull(message = ErrorConstants.SORTCODENULL)
//@Range(min = 000000)
private Integer SortCode;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - either you create your own constraint and validator (see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html) or you use either

```
@Min(100000)
@Max(999999)
private Integer SortCode;
```

or

```
@DecimalMin("100000")
@DecimalMax("999999")
private Integer SortCode;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, previously I used @Min(000001) @Max(999999) but it wasn't working for the min check. With your example it does work now